# Android Back Button Doesn't Return to Previous Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back, preferenceactivity

I have an app that has two activities: MainActivity and SettingsActivity. The MainActivity has a menu with a single Settings menu item. When this menu item is clicked, it launches the SettingsActivity with an intent. After the activity starts up, I click the back button in the top left corner and nothing happens. I assumed since I started the activity using an intent, the activity stack would be managed automatically. I want to return to the MainActivity. Am I wrong in this assumption?

**MainActivity.onMenuItemSelected**

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int itemID = item.getItemId();

    if(itemID == R.id.settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public static final String TEST = "test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add the full code of the two activities ?

Comment: You mean you click the app icon in the ActionBar and nothing happens?

Comment: can you please add the manifest also? you may add only the activities' tags

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Inside your `SettingsActivity` you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`to enable the back button on top left corner of Action Bar for going back. It does not know by itself that what it needs to do on click. Inside the case `android.R.id.home` you can just call `finish()`. This will finish your current activity and you will go back to `MainActivity` which started it. Eg:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Just for completeness, to enable the home button, you may add the following in your `onCreate()` of `SettingsActivity`:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

As per docs of [setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29)

`It is to show the user that selecting home will return one level up rather than to the top level of the app.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see this.finish() in SettingsActivity's onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my case where the up button wasn't working for an activity that I navigated to via context menu.

Comment: working on android 4.4.4, haven't tested on greater APIs

Answer (score 2):

Just add these lines in your OnCreate methord

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and override this method to add functionality to your back button:

```
   @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if(id==android.R.id.home)
    {
     finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: The point about specifying a parent activity in AndroidManifest is key, without it neither this nor Shobhit's solution will work.