# UP button does not wok in action bar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

i've started learning android programming from this source : http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

and i'm in Adding the action bar > Adding action buttons section

i use Eclipse for coding and may be there are some difference with tutorial

for now my problem is that the UP button that i added to action bar for my second activity to navigate to Main Activity does not work

it appears on the screen but when i tap on it, nothing happened

i think the problem is in my android manifest file so i put it here to guide me

Tnx in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >             

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.test.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

program is simple, in the main activity (MainActivity) user enter a text in the text field and send it to second activity (DispalyMessageActivity) by pressing send button and showing it in second activity (DispalyMessageActivity)

Comment: Add this line before the `meta-data` tag: `android:parentActivityName="com.test.MainActivity" >`

Comment: @PrerakSola : that wouldn't work, because of minsdkversion, it must be 16 or higher

Comment: Read the last segment of the tutorial where it tells you to add the following line: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @hamid_c Try answer on : [Android Back Button Doesn't Return to Previous Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643340/android-back-button-doesnt-return-to-previous-activity/17643389#17643389) if you have't overridden `onOptionsItemSelected` in your Second Activity.

Comment: @PrerakSola : i try that but no answer

Comment: @ShobhitPuri : but @ the end of tuts said that : Because the system now knows MainActivity is the parent activity for DisplayMessageActivity, when the user presses the Up button, the system navigates to the parent activity as appropriate—you do not need to handle the Up button's event.

Comment: You need to override `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Read this official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html